# Size of images for iPhone app store

Tags: iphone

what size should I export my graphics, for use in the example/screenshot section of the app on the app store.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should [read the dedicated Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) about the subject that gives every info about the icon sizes

Read this [Technical Note too](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) where every icon and artwork sizes are described in detail.

---

For the screenshots published on the AppStore, simply do a screenshot of your app for this (which will be 640x960px if you make your screenshot from an iPhone with Retina display (iPhone4), and 320x480px for iPhone 3GS or older, etc. Namely the size of the screen in pixels, obviously).

To do those screenshots:

- either directly on the device hold the Power+Home buttons together and it will display a small/quick "flash" effect on the screen to tell you the screenshot has been saved in your iPhone library
- Or from the Xcode Organizer, after you have plugged the iPhone to your Mac obviously, select the iPhone in the list and in the appropriate section of the organizer, click on the button to generate a screenshot directly from Xcode.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: Thanks. [A simple Google search](http://bit.ly/1lDNBLD) and boom ==> new link ;) — (Answer edited)

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this are answered in the Developer Guide for iTunes Connect:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

See pages 13 and 14 for size information.

Comment: The link has changed.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look for this currently is on the iTunes Connect Developer Guide under "Adding New Apps":

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW42

Answer (score 1):

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

6.5 inch (iPhone 12 Pro Max, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone 11, iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR)
1284 x 2778 pixels (portrait)
2778 x 1284 pixels (landscape)

5.8 inch (iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 12, iPhone 12 mini, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone XS, iPhone X)
1170 x 2532 pixels (portrait)
2532 x 1170 pixels (landscape)

5.5 inch (iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus)
1242 x 2208 pixels (portrait)
2208 x 1242 pixels (landscape)

4.7 inch (iPhone SE (2nd generation), iPhone 8, iPhone 7, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6)
750 x 1334 pixels (portrait)
1334 x 750 pixels (landscape)

4 inch (iPhone SE (1st generation))
640 x 1096 pixels (portrait without status bar)
640 x 1136 pixels (portrait with status bar)
1136 x 600 pixels (landscape without status bar)
1136 x 640 pixels (landscape with status bar)

3.5 inch (iPhone 4s)
640 x 920 pixels (portrait without status bar)
640 x 960 pixels (portrait with status bar)
960 x 600 pixels (landscape (without status bar)
960 x 640 pixels (landscape with status bar)

12.9 inch (iPad Pro (4th generation, 3rd generation))
2048 x 2732 pixels (portrait)
2732 x 2048 pixels (landscape)

12.9 inch (2nd generation iPad Pro)
2048 x 2732 pixels (portrait)
2732 x 2048 pixels (landscape)

11 inch (iPad Pro, 4th generation iPad Air)
1668 x 2388 pixels (portrait)
2388 x 1668 pixels (landscape)

10.5 inch (iPad (8th generation, 7th generation), iPad Pro, iPad Air)
1668 x 2224 pixels (portrait)
2224 x 1668 pixels (landscape)

9.7 inch (iPad, iPad mini)
1536 x 2008 pixels (portrait (without status bar)
1536 x 2048 pixels (portrait with status bar)
2048 x 1496 pixels (landscape without status bar)
2048 x 1536 pixels (landscape with status bar)

Mac
One of the following, with a 16:10 aspect ratio.
1280 x 800 pixels
1440 x 900 pixels
2560 x 1600 pixels
2880 x 1800 pixels

Apple TV
1920 x 1080 pixels
3840 x 2160 pixels

Apple Watch (Series 6,  Series 5, Series 4, Series 3, SE)
368 x 448 pixels